# Why multiple times save event calling of kendo grid

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I would like to calculate number of cell based on cell value change in a row. If I set value in single cell its working but when set multiple cell, save events start calling multiple time.

[Link to fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qA8QX/82/) demonstrating problem

```
// sample code goes here
```

Comment: I had to edit your link to use it: http://jsfiddle.net/qA8QX/82/

Comment: Also the save event calls every time you set the model, why is this causing an issue?

Comment: @GeorgeB I don't want to call multiple time save event as mention in above link. Please share your suggestion.